# Data from Excel to Word not applying AutoFitBehavior correctly

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, ms-word

Hoping that someone can give some advice, as I've modified my code many times now trying to get the `AutoFitBehavior` formatting to apply correctly.  The code runs through everything as is (moves everything over and completes just fine), but the AutoFit never applies. Feel like I'm missing something that should be a simple fix, but everything I see seems to be telling me that the `objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow` should work - I've tried it within its' own If statement where it is now, as well as moving it around and including in different places, with the same result.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Most recent version of my code:

```
Sub CopyToWord()

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rpt As Range

Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = False
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

ws.Range("A1:" & Split(ws.Cells(, LastColumn).Address, "$")(1) & LastRow).Copy

With objWord
    .ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 1
    .Selection.Paste
    .Visible = True
End With

If objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count <> 0 Then
    objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
End If

Application.CopyObjectsWithCells = True
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Control Panel").Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm assuming there is just the one table in the document, so AutoFit is definitely being applied to the right table... Try checking the Table.AllowAutoFit property - it needs to be True. You might also try "fiddling" with it in the Word UI until you find a combination that gives the desired result.

Comment: It is just the one table each time.  But was able to run this by some friends over the holiday, and we figured it out.  Replaced `If objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count <> 0 Then
    objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
End If` with `objWord.ActiveDocument.Tables(1).AutoFitBehavior (2)` and now  get the intended result.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked that the tables count condition is true (using debug.print)?
If not, I don't believe that an Excel Range object is simply converted into a table object in Word. You should probably use `Range.ConvertToTable`method so you can get the table object and then you can apply the auto fit thing.

Comment: IF you read the code carefully you'll see that the OP is copying and pasting into Word. Your contribution does not address the actual question, which is how to change the table's behavior in Word.

Comment: Try using `.Selection.PasteExcelTable False, True, False` instead of juste Paste. It worked for me.
Getting back to your comment, you said that you were transferring data from Excel to Word. The actual question was not clear enough and that why I used a question mark at my first sentence so I can inquire more about the issue. 
'Understand, read, know the context, then Compile'